# Use string values from an array as string variable to parse json - codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a no. of checkboxes (20), what i did is if a user select any checkbox, its name is stored in an array (eg abc array below in code). The name of the string variable that stores the respective json is of the same name as of the checkbox. For eg if Checkbox "a" is clicked, string value "a" is stored in array and there is a string variable named "a" that stores the related json values. What I need is that if i pass the string value stored in array as InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(abc.get(i).getBytes()), it should be used to parse the inputStream for json. But it gives NullPointerException since the string value "a" is not equal to string variable a. How can i solve this problem? I ran out of ideas here. Is there other ways to achieve what i want to do here?

**code: String values of the selected checkboxes are stored in an array**

```
String a = "[{\n"
        + "\t\t\t\"title\": \"title1\",\n"
        + "\t\t\t\"describ\": \"describ1\"\n"
        + "}]";

String b = "[{\n"
        + "\"title\": \"title2\",\n"
        + "\"describ\": \"describ2\"\n"
        + "}]";

String c = "[{\n"
        + "\t\t\t\"title\": \"title3\",\n"
        + "\t\t\t\"describ\": \"describ3\"\n"
        + "}]";
//and all jsons required are there

ArrayList<String> abc;
@Override
protected void beforeTestForApp(Form f) {
    f.setTitle("abc");
    abc = new ArrayList<>();
    //I have stored "a" & "b" in the abc array here for simplicity, but it is dynamic,
    //ie. if the user select checkbox c, c will be stored in abc array and so on
    abc.add("a");
    abc.add("b");
    Button bb = new Button("go");
    bb.addActionListener((e) -> {
        showForm("TestForAppResult", null);
    });
    f.add(bb);
}
```

**Form for json parser and displaying the values:**

```
@Override
protected void beforeTestForAppResult(Form f) {
    f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    InputStream is;
    for (int i = 0; i < abc.size(); i++) {
        Label heading = new Label(abc.get(i));
        f.add(heading);
        //this gives error since abc.get(i) gives string value, not string variable
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(abc.get(i).getBytes());
        showDetails(is, f);
    }
    //if i do this instead of for loop jst above, i can get the result but since what value'll be stored in an array is not known,it is not possible
          //is = new ByteArrayInputStream(a.getBytes());
          //showDetails(is, f);
          //is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b.getBytes());
          //showDetails(is, f);
}

private void showDetails(InputStream is, Form f) {
    JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
    Hashtable<String, Object> test;
    try {
        test = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(is));
        Vector aVector = (Vector) test.get("root");
        for (int j = 0; j < aVector.size(); j++) {
            Hashtable hm = (Hashtable) aVector.get(j);
            String title = (String) hm.get("title");
            String describ = (String) hm.get("describ");

            Label z = new Label(title);
            Label zz = new Label(describ);
            f.add(z);
            f.add(zz);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tbh i didnt get your problem concretely but i still try to give you some shots so you can try out.

If i understand correctly you have 20 objects which contains values underlying?
So then you have a JSONArray, just iterate trough it and grab that JSONObject.

now just use parseJSON instead of parse as it is deprecated...

here is a short snippet of my code

```
JSONArray jsonTasks = new JSONArray(responseString);
            for (int index = 0; index < jsonTasks.length(); index++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonTasks.get(index);
                            if (jsonObject != null) {
                                Map jsonMap = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonObject.toString().getBytes(UTF8)), UTF8));
                                System.out.println(jsonMap.get("date"));
```

Comment: I think you didnt get it. The string where json is stored eg String a ="[{json}]", String b="[{other json}] etc has same name as the values of the objects. If an user selects an object with value "a", i have to parse the json string variable a & so on. Moreover one can select multiple objects and i have to parse the json simultaneously.

Comment: I've read both your question and this comment and I have no idea what you are asking...